# SIP-Servlet AS and cipher-suite

Tags: restcomm

I am trying to figure out how to configure SIP-Servlet AS for cipher-suite. Any help is welcome.

Regards,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://documentation.telestax.com/core/sip_servlets/SIP_Servlets_Server_User_Guide.html#_sss_tls and SIP Stack property `gov.nist.javax.sip.gov.nist.javax.sip.ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES` which is only available in recent versions of the SIP Servlets container